# Pushing an item into array in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

I got a problem about JavaScript. Specificly, I have a table like

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label>Select</label>
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Middle)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DoB)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr id="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)" ondblclick="DoubleClickOnRow(this)">
        <td>
            <input id="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)" type="checkbox" onclick="SelectCheckBox(this)"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Middle)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DoB)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

And I declare a array to hold EmployeeId from checking the checkbox in the first column of a row. However, it says *arrayOfEmployeeId.push(id);* not a function.
By the way, I want to get array of EmployeeId to do DELETE methods in ASP.NET web api. Am I right?

```
var arrayOfEmployeeId = {};
function SelectCheckBox(thisRow)
    {
        var id = thisRow.id;
        arrayOfEmployeeId.push(id);
        console.log(arrayOfEmployeeId);
    }
```

Comment: `var arrayOfEmployeeId = {}` is not an Array, but an object, you have to do : `var arrayOfEmployeeId = [];`

Comment: Yeah, It's exactly right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arrayOfEmployeeId` is an object (`{}`). What you probably want is an array like `var arrayOfEmployeeId = [];`.

Comment: And If I want to remove a element, how can I do?

Comment: You could do: `arrayOfEmployeeId = arrayOfEmployeeId.slice(arrayOfEmployeeId.indexOf(id),1)`

Comment: Use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 0):

arrayOfEmployeeId = {}; is an object 
You can make it an array.

arrayOfEmployeeId = [];
You can use the splice method to delete like you are wanting.

Comment: Yes, I think splice is good. But I define a function for my own to use. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! Happy coding